# Stock bytes in QVariantMap

Tags: c++, qt, byte, qt5

I'm getting the bytes data from a `QImage` in a `QByteArray` and i want to write the datas from the `QByteArray` in a `QVariantMap`, but after stocking the bytes, the bytes are changed and the image is not valid...

I tried to stock the `QByteArray` directly but the thing is i'm going to receive QVariantMap (as a JSON) from Windows phone, android and iOS. And the `QByteArray` will not exist on those OS so i doubt that the `.toByteArray` function will work...

Here is an example of what i tried using a `QString` but the bytes are changed when the `QString` is filled...

```
QFile tmp("default_profile.jpg");

tmp.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

if (tmp.exists() == true)
{
    QByteArray tab;
    tab = tmp.read(tmp.size());

    int i = 0;
    char *data = tab.data();

    QString str;
    while (i != tmp.size())
    {
        if (i < 100)
            qDebug() << "AVANT = " << " i = " << i << "[" << *data + '0' << "]";
        i++;
        str.append(*data);
        ++data;
    }
    QVariantMap *tmp = new QVariantMap();   
    (*tmp)["name"] = "test.jpg";
    (*tmp)["data"] = str;
    (*tmp)["size"] = tab.size();
    (*tmp)["type"] = "PhonePic";

    this->fileReceived("", "", tmp);
}
```

And here is the `fileReceived`:

```
    QFile tmp((*src)["name"].toString());

    tmp.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Truncate);
    char *test = (char *)malloc((*src)["size"].toInt());

    QString str;
    str = (*src)["data"].toString();

    int i = 0;
    char *data = const_cast<char *>(str.toStdString().c_str());

    while (i != 8143)
    {
        if (i < 100)
            qDebug() << "AFTER = " << " i = " << i << "[" << *data + '0' << "]";
        i++;
        ++data;
    }       

    qDebug() << tmp.write(str.toStdString().c_str(), (*src)["size"].toInt());
```

The size of the "AFTER" QString is good, but the values are not good...
Does someone know what i'm doing wrong ? or maybe have an idea of how i get do it ?

Thanks for people who will try to help me.

Comment: char *data = const_cast<char *>(str.toStdString().c_str()) is not safe. The std string returned by toStdString() is destroyed at the end of the statement, so `data` will be invalid after that. `const std::string stdstr = str.toStdString(); const char* data = stdstr.c_str();` would be safe.

Answer (score 0):

You load binary data into a QByteArray. Then you append the data in this QByteArray byte by byte to a QString, which converts every single byte into unicode. And last but not least you you just try to cast this back into raw data? No way. So pointing you to what you are doing wrong was easy.

Helping you is much more difficult. Why do you think you can use QString, when QByteArray is not available? When QVariantMap is available, then you have a complete Qt. So using QByteArray should not be a problem. But I must admit, I don't fully understand your post and your problem, so I might overlook something.

Comment: The thing is, i need to transfer a file throught UDP, for that i'm using a QVariantMap which will be converted to JSON but before that, i need to put the Filedatas (so all  the bytes) in a QVariant...but the problem is that the bytes change when they are in the QString, so i'm looking for an other way to do it...

Comment: So far I can follow you. The question is why do you think you can use QString, QVariantMap, but no QByteArray.

Comment: Because i'll receive those QVariantMap from Windows phone, iphones and androids phones, and the QByteArray struct will not be natively there, so i need a simple type for stocking those bytes...

Comment: You will not receive QVariantMap from those places, because there's no such thing outside of Qt.  You can't store binary data in JSON, what you will need to do is encode it into a string, and decode on the other end.  There are many different ways the encoding could be done, base-64 is the most common and is supported directly by Qt (QByteArray::toBase64() and its counterpart fromBase64()), but it's up to you to know the format of the data you're transferring.

Comment: So is this correct: You create a QVariantMap, this is will be converted to JSON and send via UDP to a Windows phone. The other way round: Windows phone creates some other data structure, which will be converted to JSON, which will be converted to QVariantMap when you receive it? I think now I understand. And I think, the usual way is to encode the binary data to base64.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a `QImage` directly in a `QVariant` or `QVariantMap`. How the particular json library that you use will deal with the json-to-Qt interface, that's a whole another story.

Since `QVariant` is in Qt Core and not Qt Gui, you have to use `QVariant::value()` or the `qvariant_cast()` template function when working with GUI types such as `QImage`.